# Go to Top of Page when is postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ascx control which has inside a Save Button and it is at the bottom of the page. When i click the save button and it postbacks the control remains at the bottom. Is that any whay to go to top after postback?

Comment: are u doing any ajax  updates ? or form.submit() method ? if form.submit()  then it will surely work

Comment: You can do that with css and positioning, or by placing the control in real time, one time on bottom inside a place holder, the other time on top - maybe you have some issue with the ids - need some test

Comment: +1 You are the first guy who complains that the page stays where it was.

Comment: @Ravi Yes my control makes ajax updates

Comment: @user1292656 Can describe how you are doing ajax requests? Are they handled by UpdatePanel or coded manually?

Answer (score 3):

Such behaviour could be because of page property `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` set to `true`. This property could be set either programmatically or declaratively throught web.config or via page directive:

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

Check these things, I believe somewhere it is enabled.

Alternatively you can your subscribe to the `endRequest` "event" on your page and reset scroll position on each request.

```
<script>
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it is not enabled anywhere

Comment: I put it in the .ascx control but it doesn't works. The ascx control remains at the bottom

Comment: When you said that your control makes ajax request I assumed that requests were served by UpdatePanel. In case of hand coded requests you can put `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` in success/error callback javascript function.

Comment: hm my control is in an PlaceHolder, i think the scroll bars are "pieces" of placeholder which load a large control inside. maybe that's why is not working